# Regular Expression that might contain 8 or 9 numbers - how to do?

Tags: regex, digits

I use this regular expression to validate brazilian cellphones:

```
/^(\([0-9]{2}\))\s([9]{1})?([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})$/
```

Output: `(31) 8876-3234` VALID

But *Sao Paulo* state has 9 digits cellphones:

Output *SP*: `(31) 98876-3234`

Current regex needs tweak to accept that as valid too, any tips on what should I change in it?

Comment: The regex already matches the extra leading 9.

Comment: Works for me without any change. http://regexr.com?33s2j

Comment: By the way, you can simplify your regex by using `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.  Also `[9]{1}` is a character class containing only one character and repeated exactly once, which is the same as just writing `9`.

Comment: That's odd, it wasn't working. With the change mentioned bellow however, it did o.O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `{m,n}` quantifier to create a range:

```
/^(\([0-9]{2}\))\s([0-9]{4,5})-([0-9]{4})$/
```

Though your regex seems to be fine, as it has an optional `9` to match before the 4 digits. But if there is any possibility that there can be anything else than `9` there, then you can use this regex.

Comment: damn, how could I miss that in my searches? >.> Thanks a lot! - Accepting answer in 10 minutes

Comment: In a kinda non-related topic, do you know a easy way to: When I click a masked input field (with pre-defined fields), always go to the first character instead of starting from the middle of it?

Comment: @user2056484. I really don't understand what you are asking? If this topic is completely unrelated to this question, then you can probably post a new question.

Comment: Yeah sure, i'll search a bit more and I might asking it here, with more details. Thanks again for your time, have a nice day

Comment: Yeah, I had to wait a couple of minutes so i forgot ._. Done!